# Javascript play() Function not working in ie11

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I am trying to use onclick to call a function and play a file however the file does not play in ie11, plays fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Here is the code

```js
  function play1(){
       var audio1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
       audio1.play();
  }
  function play2(){
       var audio2 = document.getElementById("audio2");
       audio2.play();
  }
```

```html
<div class="audiobuttons"><a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="play1()">Play Example <i class="icon-white icon-play"></i></a></div><br /><audio id="audio1" src="training/example7.wav" ></audio></div>
<div class="audiobuttons"><a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="play2()">Play Example <i class="icon-white icon-play"></i></a></div><br /><audio id="audio2" src="training/example8.wav" ></audio></div>
```

Comment: any useful information in the browsers developer tools console

Comment: Did you try to go with adding click event with addEventListener, instead using onlick attribute ?

Comment: @JaromandaX nope :(

Comment: @Belmin Just did, no luck

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer 11 does not support .wav files, it was added in Edge

[image]

http://caniuse.com/#feat=wav

Comment: Thats ie9. The page also runs this on load <embed id="myAudio" src="training/D020.wav" autostart="true" hidden="true"></embed> and it plays just fine.

Comment: Sure, that image was misleading, but it still doesn't support .wav

Comment: Why does this code work then? <embed id="myAudio" src="training/D020.wav" autostart="true" hidden="true"></embed>

Comment: @Da11aS - don't know, but both caniuse and MSDN says it's so.

Answer (score 0):

As @adeneo correctly mentions, IE11 does not support WAV files. I had this issue and found that a simple file conversion to **MP3** files solved my issues. It has much greater support.

For more info, see here:
https://caniuse.com/#search=mp3